# How to mock interface extending JpaRepository in Unit tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have this PersonServiceImpl class that I am testing:

```
package com.personregistrationspring.service;

import com.personregistrationspring.model.Person;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.Name;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.Address;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.Contact;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.dto.PersonDto;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.Role;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.Contact;
import com.personregistrationspring.repository.PersonRepository;
import com.personregistrationspring.repository.RoleRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;

import java.util.*;


@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{
    
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public PersonServiceImpl(PersonRepository personRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository){
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }
    
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public PersonDto createPerson(PersonDto personDto){


        Person person = mapToEntity(personDto);
        
        Set<Integer> roleIds = personDto.getRoleIds();
        
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        
        for(Integer roleId : roleIds){
            Optional<Role> optionalRole = roleRepository.findById(roleId);
            if(optionalRole.isPresent()){
                Role role = optionalRole.get();
                roles.add(role);
            } else{
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Role does not exist");
            }
        }
        person.setRoles(roles);
        Person createdPerson = personRepository.save(person);
        return mapToDto(createdPerson);
    }
```

and I have this Test class setup:

```
package com.personregistrationspring;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.Role;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.RoleEnum;
import com.personregistrationspring.repository.PersonRepository;
import com.personregistrationspring.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.Person;
import com.personregistrationspring.model.dto.PersonDto;
import com.personregistrationspring.service.PersonServiceImpl;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import java.util.*;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.any;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
@SpringBootTest
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.personregistrationspring.repository")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
public class PersonServiceImplTests {

    @Mock
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Mock
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonServiceImpl personService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void createPerson_shouldCreatePerson(){
        PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto();
        Role role = new Role(1, RoleEnum.ADMIN, null);
        personDto.setRoleIds(Set.of(1));
        List<Role> mockRoles = Arrays.asList(
                new Role(1, RoleEnum.ADMIN, null),
                new Role(2, RoleEnum.DEV, null),
                new Role(3, RoleEnum.QA, null)
        );
        when(roleRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(mockRoles);
        List<Role> roles = roleRepository.findAll();
        
        System.out.println(role.getRoleName());
        System.out.println(personDto.getRoleIds());
        System.out.print(roleRepository.);
        when(roleRepository.findById(eq(1))).thenReturn(Optional.of(role));
        PersonDto createdPersonDto = personService.createPerson(personDto);

        assertNotNull(createdPersonDto);

    }
```

The problem that I am having is that when this line in the main PersonServiceImpl is being run :
Optional optionalRole = roleRepository.findById(roleId);

It returns null which in turn would throw the exception "EntityNotFoundException"

I have tried instead of mocking the roleRepository I tried autowiring it, but when the method in the main PersonServiceImpl class is run it returns a null instance of the roleRepository there.
Am I missing something or is there something wrong with the test?

I only have one RoleRepository interface and I don't have any special configurations, only spring security basic authentication.

I also debugged the test, when checking the mock Ids created by Mockito for the instances of roleRepository, the ids are different for the instance in the test class and is also different from the main class. I dunno if that is the correct behavior for mockito.

Sample ids:
This is for the test class instance:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dax9b.png)
and here is the main class instance:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifyoq.png)

UDPATE: I have updated the test class and its corresponding test:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class PersonServiceImplTests {

```
@Mock
private PersonRepository personRepository;

@Mock
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

@InjectMocks
private PersonServiceImpl personService;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void createPerson_shouldCreatePerson(){
    PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto();
    Role role = new Role(1, RoleEnum.ADMIN, null);
    personDto.setRoleIds(Set.of(1));

    when(roleRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(role));

    PersonDto createdPersonDto = personService.createPerson(personDto);

    assertNotNull(createdPersonDto);

}
```

I also forgot to mention that I am using a PostgreSQL database when running the main program

Answer (score 1):

About @SpringBootTest (from baeldung)
`The @SpringBootTest annotation is useful when we need to bootstrap the entire container. The annotation works by creating the ApplicationContext that will be utilized in our tests.`

Since you are mocking all the dependent objects you do not need to boot the container, and can use junit's `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` instead.

Also do not need to import configurations for the repositories/hibernate/etc.

With the empty response from the mocked roleRepository, it looks like the mock is not set up properly, since you are definitely looking for role 1.

I don't think this is required: (Could be affecting the mock classes without closing?)

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}
```

Also,
You are not providing a mock behavior for mocked PersonRepository, the save method is called: `personRepository.save(person);`

ie:

```
when(personRepository.save(any()).thenReturn(personObjectWithId);
```

---

---

---

Here is a minimal reproduced working example (tested):
(personRepository.save() has not been mocked and therefor returns null, so the final check in the test is for null)

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class PersonServiceTests {
    @Mock
    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Mock
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    private PersonService personService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto();
        personDto.setRoleIds(Set.of(1));

        Role role = new Role(1, RoleEnum.ADMIN, null);
        when(roleRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(role));
        PersonDto createdPersonDto = personService.createPerson(personDto);

        assertNull(createdPersonDto);
    }
}
```

Here is a minimal PersonService class to reproduce the problem only:

```
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PersonService(PersonRepository personRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    public PersonDto createPerson(PersonDto personDto) {
        Set<Integer> roleIds = personDto.getRoleIds();
        for (Integer roleId : roleIds) {
            Optional<Role> optionalRole = roleRepository.findById(roleId);
            if (optionalRole.isPresent()) {
                Role role = optionalRole.get();
                System.out.println(role);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Role does not exist");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem that I am experiencing is that the role Repository can't find the roleId that I am passing through in the createPerson() method when I call the createPerson() method.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the answer, try using @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) since you are mocking all dependency classes

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but sadly is still failing with the same result. I have also commented the setUp() when I ran the test with your suggestion

Comment: I have added a fully working and tested example at the bottom of the answer

Comment: I recreated your test, and it is still failing, the line that is giving out the error is in the PersonServiceImpl code proper inside the for loop. When I call the roleRepository in the test class it finds the role but when it is time to call it to perform the createPerson() method in the PersonServiceImpl and it reaches the for loop it can't find the role now

Comment: @Saida You have roles 1, 2, and 3. Do you mock all of those, or only 1?

Comment: @DavidConrad I am only mocking one, the List was just to test something when debugging.

Comment: @Saida Are you able to share what you have now?

Comment: @CodeMoneky934783 I have updated the test class as shown above

Comment: Is your test still passing @CodeMoneky934783?

Comment: @Saida you are missing the lines to mock the response from roleRepository.findById()
`when(roleRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(role));`

Comment: @CodeMoneky934783 even when I add that line that you are suggesting it doesn't make a difference because when we reach the for loop it will still say that the role does not exist

Comment: @CodeMoneky934783 I have added the line that you suggested and it still returns the same failed result.

Comment: perhaps you have the wrong version of Junit or Mockito or something like that